# Logsoftmax stability

Tags: numerical, softmax, underflow, numerical-stability

I know how to make softmax stable by adding to element -max _i x_i. This avoids overflow and underflow. 
Now, taking log of this can cause underflow. log softmax(x) can evaluate to zero, leading to -infinity.

I am not sure how to fix it. I know this is a common problem. I read several answers on it, which I didn't understand. But I am still confused on how to solve this problem.

PS: If you provide a simple example, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 13):

In order to stabilize `Logsoftmax`, most implementations such as [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/log_softmax) and [Thenao](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-dev/Vg08s2UegHU), use a trick which takes out the largest component `max(x_i)`. This trick is often used for stably computing `softmax`. For `logsoftmax`, we begin with:

[image: formula]

After extracting out the `exp(b)` and using the fact that `log(exp(x)) = x`, we have:

[image: formula]

If we set [image: b = max(x_i)], this new equation has both overflow and underflow stability conditions.

---

In terms of code, if `x` is a vector:

```py
def log_softmax(x):
    x_off = x - np.max(x)
    return x_off - np.log(np.sum(np.exp(x_off)))
```

---

See also: https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/

Answer (score 1):

```
logsoftmax = logits - log(reduce_sum(exp(logits), dim))
```

refer: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/log_softmax

Answer (score 0):

Just use this as it take care of Nan

```py
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels, logits, axis=-1, name=None
)
```

```py
logits = tf.constant([[4, 5, 1000]], dtype = tf.float32)
labels = tf.constant([[1,0,1]], dtype = tf.float32)

# Case-1 
output = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)
print(output) 
>>> tf.Tensor([996.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)

#Case-2
a = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
output = tf.reduce_sum(-(labels * tf.math.log(a)))
print(output) 
>>> tf.Tensor(nan, shape=(), dtype=float32)


# this happens because value of softmax truncates to zero

print(a) 
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score -1):

Mathematical tricks cannot help you create `log 0` be something other that -inf.
If you think it trough, the only way is you normalize the data so that you don't end in there.